# Блоки друг под другом в мобильной версии

Tags: html, css, responsive

Есть три блока в ряд разной ширины. Как можно сделать их адаптивными, чтобы в мобильной версии они были друг под другом?

```css
.watch {
  float: none;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50px;
  width: 224px;
  height: 69px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #918A83;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

.watch-elements {
  margin: 20px 20px;
}

.watch p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.mouse {
  bottom: 0;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #DAD3CC;
  width: 577px;
  height: 69px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.mouse-elements {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.mouse p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
}

.chat-bot {
  bottom: 20px;
  float: right background-color: #09A753;
  border-radius: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  width: 227px;
  height: 39px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chat-bot img {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.chat-bot p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -15px;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .watch img {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
  }
  .watch p {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <h2 class="header-text">Practical business advice and knowhow<br>customized to your needs</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-left">
    <div class="watch">
      <div class="watch-elements">
        <img src="assets/img/icons/icon2.svg">
        <p>Watch Presenation</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="mouse">
      <div class="mouse-elements">
        <img src="assets/img/icons/Icon1.svg"><br>
        <p>Scroll Down</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-right">
    <div class="chat-bot">
      <img src="assets/img/06w.png">
      <p>Hi, can I help you?</p>
      <img src="assets/img/icons/icon3.svg" style="float: right; margin-right: -60px; margin-top: -39px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Они у меня друг на друга накладываются. Вот как на картинке сделал:[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Я приписал к каждому блоку свойство `float`, но не помогло

Comment: Тут ели родитель должен быть к примеру `flex`'ом или у блоков добавьте обтекание `float`

Comment: У Вас еще разметка бутстрапа ее здесь нет. Так же сами блоки не нужно позиционировать абсолютно

Comment: @RuslanSemenov  я исправил кое-что. Посмотрите пожалуйста еще раз. Мне очень нужно понять как сделать их адаптивными

Comment: Я же сказал, убрать абсолютное позиционирование. С ним ничего работать не будет

Comment: @RuslanSemenov убрал

Answer (score 0):

Очень много лишнего убирать и убирать, советую почитать бутстраповские классы, там почти все есть. Вот на быструю руку.

```css
.np>* {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.watch {
  height: 69px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #918A83;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

.watch-elements {
  margin: 20px 20px;
}

.watch p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.mouse {
  border: 1px solid #DAD3CC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 69px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.mouse-elements {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.mouse p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
}

.chat-bot {
  background-color: #09A753;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 39px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.chat-bot>* {
  display: block;
}

.chat-bot img {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.chat-bot p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col my-4">
      <h2 class="header-text">Practical business advice and knowhow<br>customized to your needs</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row np">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-left watch">
      <div class="watch-elements">
        <img src="assets/img/icons/icon2.svg">
        <p>Watch Presenation</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="mouse">
        <div class="mouse-elements">
          <img src="assets/img/icons/Icon1.svg"><br>
          <p>Scroll Down</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-right align-items-center">
      <div class="chat-bot">
        <img src="assets/img/06w.png">
        <p>Hi, can I help you?</p>
        <img src="assets/img/icons/icon3.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Semenov, спасибо Вам. Можно еще спросить как между ними расстояние добавить и прижать их к низу секции?

Comment: Расстояния куча вариантов,  если внутренне то padding наружное margin. Если нужно разделить блоки нужно использовать offset

Comment: Semenov, а прижать как можно?